# Should I dispose of X509Certificate2?

Tags: c#, identityserver4, idisposable, x509certificate2, asp.net-core-2.2

I'm using IdentityServer4 and I want to load signing certificate from file. For example,

```
var certificate = new X509Certificate2(
        path, 
        password, 
        X509KeyStorageFlags.EphemeralKeySet);

services.AddIdentityServer()
        .AddSigningCredential(certificate)
...
certificate.Dispose();
```

The code above won't work when I request the token from IdentityServer. But it will work in case I remove `certificate.Dispose();`.

I also tried another option. I created `RsaSecurityKey` from certificate's private key and used it for adding signing credential. And in this case disposing will not break anything.

```
var rsk = new RsaSecurityKey(certificate.GetRSAPrivateKey()))

services.AddIdentityServer()
        .AddSigningCredential(rsk)
...
certificate.Dispose()
```

So my question is more general. Should I dispose `X509Certificate2` object created from the existing certificate?

---

From [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate2?view=netframework-4.8#remarks):

> Starting with the .NET Framework 4.6, this type implements the IDisposable interface. When you have finished using the type, you should dispose of it either directly or indirectly.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

By looking at .NET Core source code, **X509Certificate2** and its base class **X509Certificate** use class **CertificatePal** to deal with the certificate. The **[CertificatePal](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/3c30357d51b96339021b4ee52f38445c31248bb2/src/System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates/src/Internal/Cryptography/Pal.Windows/CertificatePal.cs)** class supports creation of objects of the class from various sources: blob, file, certificate store. It calls Windows CryptoAPI to get a handle to the certificate when creating the object. So, after using the object, it would be necessary to free the resources pointed to by the handle. The good news is that, the handle is stored in a **SafeCertContextHandle** object, which is guaranteed to close the handle after garbage collector collects the **X509Certificate2** object and finishes calling the finalizers of the objects. My understanding is that, we don't need to call the ***Dispose*** method manually.

Comment: I read the blog post below last night and it got me looking into this issue as well:
https://snede.net/the-most-dangerous-constructor-in-net/

My code is using the constructor and never disposing or calling the `Reset` method.

On my local machine, dev, and staging servers I did not see more than two files within the past year in the various folders that Microsoft uses to store the files for `x509Certficate2` so I guess the garbage collection is cleaning it up as you said.

Answer (score 5):

No, you should not dispose certificate object while the application runs, because when requested, IdentityServer will attempt to use disposed certificate object and will fail.

Comment: Yeah, that's reasonable in the first case. But with `RsaSecurityKey` I can dispose certificate. I wonder if I use the certificate properly, maybe there is another way.